# Adding int to char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

So I have a char array in C...for example:

```
uchar arr[3] = { 0x34, 0x45, 0xFF }
```

I am looking for a fast way to add an integer to it (like its 0x3445FF) so for example if I add 2 to arr I get:

```
{ 0x34, 0x46, 0x01 }
```

Comment: Manually convert the initial array to an `int`, add, convert back.

Comment: Is there a specific range of the length of the array? It may be possible to perform some evil bit-level hacking, I think. And also your CPU type?

Comment: @pmg beware of endianness.

Comment: I am doing this in a OpenCL kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and best way will be to convert to int, add, and then convert back. Also, you need to decide on the byte-order since it's never clear.

This code assumes big-endian, i.e. the array initially holds the number 0x3445ff:

```
uint8_t arr[] = { 0x34, 0x45, 0xff };

uint32_t x = (arr[0] << 16) | (arr[1] << 8] | arr[2];

x += 2;

arr[0] = (x >> 16) & 0xff;
arr[1] = (x >> 8) & 0xff;
arr[2] = x & 0xff;
```

Comment: The byte order required is implicit in the question and is as you have it here. The code will work regardless of the natural byte order execution platform.  I assumed that is rather the point - platform independent byte ordering?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the loop

```
int index = last_valid_index;
while(index >= 0 && addend > 0) {
    addend += array[index];
    array[index] = addend;
    addend >>= 8;
    --index;
}
```

is fast enough?

Answer (score 1):

This is C. You can probably cast the char array to the integer array and assign directly, something like

```
uchar arr[20];
((int *)arr + index/sizeOf(int)) = your_int;
```

However the size, low/big endian and the like will depend on how exactly int is represented on your platform. This may cause portability issues. Also, mind that all values from 00 till FF are possible. For instance, if you use null terminator later, the 00 in the middle will create a problems for you. Also, in my sample code, the integer representations will the sizeOf(int) - aligned.

Comment: I will try this when I get home...I am doing this in OpenCL C (the kernel) so portability shouldn't be an issue!